# Implement Z = k*Z to model a population growth

Tags: r, excel

What would be your scholarly recommendation to model a population within R when

```
DELTA_Z = .2Z, Z0 = 10
```

? The output should be similar to the following

Or as another example, suppose a population is described by the model 
`Nt+1 = 1.5Nt` and `N5 = 7.3`. Find `Nt`  for t = 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4.

```
t 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
Zt 10 12 14.4 17.28 20.736 24.8832 29.8598
```

Those recursions i.e. Z=k*Z are done quite easily within a spreadsheet such as Excel. In R however, the following (far from efficient) have been done thus far:

```
#loop implementation in R
Z=10;Z;for (t in 6:0)
    {Z=.2*Z+Z; print(Z)}
```

pr

```
Z0=10; 
Z1=.2*Z0+Z0; Z2=.2*Z1+Z1; Z3=.2*Z2+Z2   
Z4=.2*Z3+Z3;Z5=.2*Z4+Z4;Z6=.2*Z5+Z5
Zn=c(Z0,Z1,Z2,Z3,Z4,Z5,Z6);
```

Since R tries to avoid `for` loops and iterations at all costs, what would be your recommendation (could it be done preferably without iteration?)

What has been done in Excel is the following:

```
t   Nt  
5   7.3 k=1.5
4   =B2/$C$2    
3   =B3/$C$2    
2   =B4/$C$2    
1   =B5/$C$2    
0   =B6/$C$2
```

Comment: @dirk thank you what about

Answer (score 3):

It is a lot easier:

```
R> Z <- 10
R> Z * 1.2 ^ (0:6)
[1] 10.00000 12.00000 14.40000 17.28000 20.73600 24.88320 29.85984
R>
```

We set `Z` to ten, and then multiply it by the growth rate. And that is really just taking 'growth' to the `t`-th power.

There is a nice short tutorial in the appendix of the [An Introduction to R](https://cran.rstudio.com/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html) manual that came with your copy of R.  I went over that a number of times when I started.

Comment: That's okay if you can work out the closed form of the process. What about `Z = c * Z * (1-Z)` repeated? With a spreadsheet, just copy the formula. With R, write a loop.